# Can I use pattern matching to parse XML in Erlang?

Tags: xml, erlang

I've got a newbie question.

I'm trying to parse a xml message with pattern matching in functions

A sample of a message is:

```
    <msg> <action type="xxx"... />  </msg>
```

What I would like to able to do is ( sort of )

```erlang
decode_msg_in( << $<,$m,$s,$g,$>, Message/binary, $<,$/,$m,$s,$g,$> >>, R ) ->
```

The decode does not work (obviously, it's only a indication on what I'd like to do).

Is this even possible?

Does anyone have an idea? Or do I need to "iterate" the whole message as a list, building new "words"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i probably think you need to read about [Bit syntax expressions](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#bit-syntax), [Binary Comprehensions](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#binary-comprehensions) and about this xml parser library called [erlsom](http://erlsom.sourceforge.net/erlsom.htm), download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlsom/files/latest/download). You will be brought up to speed in what you want to do.
**EDIT**

---

The xml message may reach your server as a binary, or as a string: Which ever way it does, the xml parser provided can parse the xml data into Erlang terms. Using the `erlsom` library, here is an example for your xml structure. I have my `erlsom` library in code path.

```
C:\Windows\System32>erl
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> XML = "<msg><action type=\"xxx\"/>message</msg>".
"<msg><action type=\"xxx\"/>message</msg>"
2> erlsom:simple_form(XML).
{ok,{"msg",[],[{"action",[{"type","xxx"}],[]},"message"]},
    []}
3> {_,Parsed,_} = erlsom:simple_form(XML).
{ok,{"msg",[],[{"action",[{"type","xxx"}],[]},"message"]},
    []}
4> Parsed.
{"msg",[],[{"action",[{"type","xxx"}],[]},"message"]}
5> {_,_,[{_,[{_,ActionType}],_},Message]} = Parsed.
{"msg",[],[{"action",[{"type","xxx"}],[]},"message"]}
6> ActionType.
"xxx"
7> Message.
"message"
8>
```

You can see above that it comes down to easy pattern matching. The resulting structure will give you something clean as long as the senders send properly formatted `xml data`. If you suspect improper xml data to hit your server, then, you need to wrap the parser in 
`try [CALL] of [GoodResult] ->  [Action1] catch _Error:_Reason -> [Action2] end.` 
Note that if the XML Body is very large, you need to use `SAX method` to parse the xml to avoid big memory foot prints. SAX examples are included in the library documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Didn't know there was one more xml parser out there. This not really what I had in mind ... not entirely. It was more about the raw parsing. Most existing parsers require a DTD (I'm assuming erlsom does too) and I don't have a DTD, it's more happy-go-lucky hacking. The tutorial links helped a lot though!

Comment: No not really, the example i have showed you above doesnot require a DTD. Do not fear! Read the documentation. its direct. You will not need a DTD.