# Convert 1 GB XML file to ets and dets in Erlang

Tags: xml, file, erlang

I need to extract some data from a 1 GB XML file into `<key,value>` tables using ets and dets. I have searched the whole web and also in here but I did not find any simple example on how to handle big XML files.

For the beginning I just want to understand how to read the file without uploading the whole of it into memory.

Comment: reading the file: `{ok,S} = file:open("XMLFile.xml",[read]), Line = io:get_line(S,'')` . At the end, the `Line == eof`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

come on !  What you need is a [SAX XML parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) called [Erlsom](http://erlsom.sourceforge.net/erlsom.htm#sax_mode). For small files, its possible to load it all into memory and then parse it as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9663655/431620) i gave to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9663579/431620). But, for your case, these big files need the SAX method.  The Sax examples are [here](http://erlsom.sourceforge.net/erlsom.htm#sax_mode).
SAX ensures that you do not load a file into memory to parse it. The tokens that the parser gets , is what it gives to you. You will need an advanced skill of tail recursion, pattern matching and stateful programming.
**EDIT**

---

Now, [download erlsom](https://github.com/edwardw/erlsom), and extract it into your erlang `lib` , a location where all built-in applications are located. Rename its extraction folder like this: `erlsom-1.0`. Create a file called: `Emakefile` in the `erlsom-1.0` folder. Put this inside that file and save.

```
{"src/*", [verbose,report,warn_obsolete_guard,{outdir, "ebin"}]}.
```

The erlsom-1.0 folder, should look like this:

```
erlsom-1.0
 |-doc/
 |-ebin/
 |-examples/
 |-include/
 |-src/
 |-Emakefile
```

The rest of the other files do not matter. Now, open an erlang shell, whose `pwd()` is looking into the `erlsom-1.0` folder. Run the function: `make:all().` like this

```
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> make:all().
Recompile: src/ucs
Recompile: src/erlsom_writeHrl
Recompile: src/erlsom_write
Recompile: src/erlsom_ucs
Recompile: src/erlsom_simple_form
Recompile: src/erlsom_sax_utf8
Recompile: src/erlsom_sax_utf16le
Recompile: src/erlsom_sax_utf16be
Recompile: src/erlsom_sax_list
Recompile: src/erlsom_sax_lib
Recompile: src/erlsom_sax_latin1
Recompile: src/erlsom_sax
Recompile: src/erlsom_pass2
Recompile: src/erlsom_parseXsd
Recompile: src/erlsom_parse
Recompile: src/erlsom_lib
Recompile: src/erlsom_compile
Recompile: src/erlsom_add
Recompile: src/erlsom
up_to_date
2>
```

So, its done. So if the folder `erlsom-1.0` is in your erlang `lib`, then,  you can call the erlsom methods from any erlang shell whichever `pwd()` it may have.

Comment: you know how to install Erlsom on Ubuntu?

Comment: erlsom is just another erlang application. Just put it in your erlang `lib` ( a location in your erlang installation PATH where you find `mnesia`, `stdlib`, e.t.c)

Comment: i am writing a SAX example for you, then i will update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much i succeed with erlsom installation and it looks much better then xmerl. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [xmerl library](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/index.html)?

Comment: Yes i did, i couldn't understand what is going on there so i look for simple example.

Answer (score 0):

For reading big files and without loading it entirely into memory, you could use [file:open/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2), doing something like this:

```
 {ok, FileHandler} = file:open(File, [read, raw, read_ahead]),
 {ok, Line} = file:read_line(FileHandler)
```

Also, for working with XML, in Erlang you have xmerl, which unfortunately, is pretty poor documented.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Erlang, but it seems that it is possible to integrate C libraries. If you are willing to go that path, I can recommend that you have a look at the [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) library. It is the quickes, light-weight xml parser library i know. A simple callback mechanism calls your code of each xml-element and you can decide for yourself whether you want to keep it in memory or if you want to skip it.

I know, this is very low-level. But for very large data this is, sadly, often the only way to do it.

Here is something I found googling: http://dudefrommangalore.blogspot.de/2009/04/erlang-xml-parser-comparison.html